# "No qualifying bean" for repository in Groovy Spring JPA application

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-data-jpa

I know there are a **bunch** of similar questions on this topic, however all of them that I've found so far are either not quite my situation, or refer to one of the following solutions that from what I've read is either outdated or inapplicable:

- @EnableJpaRepositories annotation - taken care of by @SpringBootApplication
- @Repository annotation - not needed when extending Repository interface

The error:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean 
of type 'com.package.repository.ChannelBalanceAdjustmentRepository' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

And another error message:

```
CashReinvestDividendSpec > test FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException at DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790
```

The repository:

```
package com.package.repository

import com.package.domain.Channel
import com.package.domain.ChannelBalanceAdjustment
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

import java.time.LocalDate

interface ChannelBalanceAdjustmentRepository extends CrudRepository<ChannelBalanceAdjustment, Long>{

    ChannelBalanceAdjustment findByTypeAndChannelAndValueDate(ChannelBalanceAdjustment.Type type, Channel channel, LocalDate valueDate)
}
```

The application class:

```
package com.package

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class ProcessPendingDividendsApplication {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProcessPendingDividendsApplication, args)
    }

}
```

Excerpt from where the repository is used:

```
package com.package.service
// imports

@Service
@Slf4j
class ProcessingPendingDividendsService {


    @Autowired
    ChannelBalanceAdjustmentRepository channelBalanceAdjustmentRepository
```

And it is used in the Spock test I'm running:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
class CashReinvestDividendSpec extends Specification{

    @Autowired
    CashReinvestDividendRepository cashReinvestDividendRepository

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager entityManager

    def "test" () {
```

I can add anything else needed but don't want to clutter up the question with irrelevant stuff.

Comment: weird in my opinion!  can you maybe share project on github so that we can see it in more detail?

Comment: is that the whole error? Sometimes spring cusses about some error during creation, and then few lines down it writes the message about unsatisfied dependency which it failed to instantiate

Comment: @soung No, it's closed source.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Not the whole stack trace, but that's the part at the bottom, which should be the root cause.

Comment: @nasch if I recall it's usually not part of same stacktrace

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I added the only other error message I see, including when running with --stacktrace option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-check your entity. I've seen this before where the jpa repository has to reference a correctly configured entity, and if the entity object is missing @Entity or one of the columns is not configured correctly, it throws a red herring error.

Answer (score 0):

nasch
Are you sharing actual code/error snippets
Few observations

1. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean
   of type 'com.package.repository.ChannelBalanceAdjustmentRepository'
   how you can have a package name containing package.. its a reserverd keyword and  will not be allowed.
2. Your repository which is in a different package and without public keyword how its accessible in the service package.

Comment: No, these are obfuscated package names.  And this is groovy, not Java - "public" is the default access level.